# Pandas don't recognize "||" as string to split

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

I'm trying to split a DataFrame in two columns and get the left part in result, but pandas don't recognize that string and give me an out in empty.

```
q=['Sar || var','lol ||']
y=pd.DataFrame(q)
split_data = y[0].str.split("||", n = 1, expand = False).str[0]
print(split_data)

out

0    
1    
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Comment: `|` is a special char, you need to escape:  `\|\|`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation is somewhat deceptive for this method. What is happening is that for patterns longer than 1 character, pandas interprets the separator as a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). You can see the implementation [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/29d6b0232aab9576afa896ff5bab0b994760495a/pandas/core/strings.py#L1477).

You can use `"||"` as a literal, non-regex separator by escaping the character `"|"` (which has special meaning in regular expressions) using a backslash:

```
series.str.split("\\|\\|")
```

Note that python provides a "raw" [syntax](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) for string literals that can be useful for writing regular expressions, removing the need to escape the backslashes themselves:

```
series.str.split(r"\|\|")
```

You can consult the documentation for the `re` module for a list of special characters that will need to be escaped when using multi-character separators. Alternatively, just use the function `re.escape`:

```
import re
series.str.split(re.escape("||"))
```

Comment: TY @ApproachingDarknessFish !! Couldn't figure out what was going wrong and you solved my exact problem!